# How to write UTF-8 encoded PDF-Files using PDFBox?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, pdfbox

I have written the following code:

```
document = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage();
document.addPage( page );

PDFont font = PDTrueTypeFont.loadTTF( document, new File("c:/windows/fonts/ARIALUNI.ttf"));   
font.setFontEncoding(new PdfDocEncoding()); 


//PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);


contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.setFont( font, 12 );
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount( 100, 700 );
contentStream.drawString( "ग्रीटिंग आण्विक" );
contentStream.endText();
contentStream.close();
document.save("E:\\amitpdfbox.pdf");
document.close();
```

But the text displayed in PDF files is not proper.

It displays something like this: `þÿ    **M0@?ˇ#M5?**`.

**What should I do resolve this issue?**

Please let me know how to set UTF-8 encoding and also how to make it able to support Hindi, Marathi, etc. (Indian languages).

Comment: Is the text literally embedded in your source code? If so, have you checked that the string itself is correct? Perhaps the problem is with how you're compiling.

Comment: Are you sure the source code encoding is good? Try a `System.out.println` of the same String.

Comment: @Thilo yes it looks proper by syso the same string              String myString = new String("ग्रीटिंग आण्विक");                           System.out.println(myString);      o/p is:: ग्रीटिंग आण्विक

Comment: The hindi characters could be displayed with an embedded font on the PDF. Make sure ARIALUNI is the proper unicode font or it will not display these unicode characters. Try this one: http://gov.bih.nic.in/HindiFonts.htm